# ActionbarCompat. cannot resolve style

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-studio, android-support-library

I am not able to use ActionbarCompat. I managed to add the v7 support library. but now when i change the android:theme in the manifest to **@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar** . It is not able to **resolve** it

I'm using the Android studio 2.0

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by the Android Studio. It will say that **@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar** can't be resolved. But it will work just fine

Comment: Yes, Android Studio is very stupid this way.  Unfortunately I have not discovered a way to forego this error yet...

Comment: What do you mean it will work just fine? I can't run the project with this error, did you delete the theme or what?

Comment: it has been a long time ago. I might disabled the error message in android studio, but i am not sure.